# Regex to don't allow dots in email at wrong position

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email

I have to validation emails from a company. The regex should validate if it come from the company and could come from John.

My regex looks like this now:

`/[a-z0-9.]*(john)[a-z0-9.]*@mycompany\.com/`

The only problem, it's allows dots in wrong place.
I see valid this emails:

`john@mycompany.com
smith.john@mycompany.com
john.smith@mycompany.com`

But i shouldn't see valid these:

`john.@mycompany.com
.john@mycompany.com`

Comment: So don't allow the first group to have dots. There are numerous questions about validating emails. Maybe go check a few of them out.

Comment: Are you testing them as separate strings? Try [`^\b[a-z0-9.]*(john)[a-z0-9.]*\b@mycompany\.com$`](https://regex101.com/r/u47ppg/1).

Comment: How many email addresses does John have at this company, and why don't you validate against that list?

Comment: Actually there are the most common name here that, and a john can have multiple alias emails, so not easy to make and maintain a full list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^([a-z0-9][a-z0-9.]*)?(john)([a-z0-9.]*[a-z0-9])?@mycompany\.com$/`

This should make sure that characters before/after `(john)` don't start/end with a `.` respectively.

Comment: Actually it's do the half thing, `john.@mycompany.com` is invalid, but `.john@mycompany.com` is still valid. But still thank you for the help :)

Comment: @aboutus You're welcome. My bad! Add `^` on the left and `$` on the right. That defines start/end of string. This should work if you check one address at a time. 
I put the resulting expression in the reply.

Comment: Yes-yes, only on at a time. Thank you, with your help i understand regex better now :)

Comment: @aboutus oh by the way: You do not need the `(` `)` around `john` for the expression to work. It's a group definition that could be used for various things (backreferences, alternatives, match-group), but you don't seem to use either of those. I just let those parentheses in there as you had them in your expression and I don't know what your plans with `john` are ;p

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution

`^(?!\.)[a-z0-9.]*(john)(?:[a-z0-9]|\.(?!@))*@mycompany\.com$`

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
\w+(john)?\.?\w+?@mycompany\.com
```

This matches

```
john@mycompany.com
smith.john@mycompany.com
john.smith@mycompany.com
```

But not

```
john.@mycompany.com
.john@mycompany.com
```

In the last case it actually grabs only the part after the dot

```
john@mycompany.com
```

Answer (score 0):

when I wrote my answer you already got many answers. :-) Ok, here is other what you can test.

```
^([[:alnum:]]+\.)?john(\.[[:alnum:]]+)?@mycompany\.com
```

I tested on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

If I understood well before and after *john* should be some word delimited by dot `.`